# How to enable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp?

Tags: mysql

When I try to start my mySQL server I get message:

> [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.
>   
> Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see
>   documentation for more details).

I find answer on:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

But how to enable it? Where?

Comment: see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-default-configuration-file.html

Comment: Why is it not telling what it expects?

Answer (score 80):

First you don't need to change anything yet.

> Those nonstandard behaviors remain the default for TIMESTAMP but as of
>   MySQL 5.6.6 are deprecated and this warning appears at startup

Now if you want to move to [new behaviors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp) you have to add this line in your `my.cnf` in the [mysqld] section.

```
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

The location of my.cnf (or other config files) vary from one system to another. If you can't find it refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/using-system-variables.html you have to set boolean values using 0/1 in an options file. (I wanted to edit the post but it's  only allowed if you edit at least 6 chars.)

Comment: Just to clarify, the values True/False work just as well as 1/0.

Comment: i have a my-default.ini file and after adding explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE it is still giving the same warning.What shoud i do.I am using windows 8 64 bit

Comment: In which of all the sections of my.cnf should I add that line?

Comment: `my.cnf` is `my.ini` in windows it should be in `pathTo\MySQL\data\MySQL Server 5.6`

Comment: @JunaidShirwani you can use search for `my.ini` inside mysql folder if you can't find it

Comment: i  have done that . the only file i can find is my-deafault.ini

Comment: It's falsely stated that nonstandard behaviour was until MySQL 5.6.6. According to this table: https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/new-defaults-in-mysql-8-0/ `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` was set to False until MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 34):

In your mysql command line do the following:

```sql
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timestamp%';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | OFF   |
| log_timestamps                  | UTC   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> SET GLOBAL explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timestamp%';
+---------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                   | Value |
+---------------------------------+-------+
| explicit_defaults_for_timestamp | ON    |
| log_timestamps                  | UTC   |
+---------------------------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @Prasanna please paste the text next time

Comment: I second the motion to please paste the text next time ... including an image of text has got to be some kind of foul. It's definitely some kind of evil.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 18

Comment: Though being able to read the current value being used is absolutely invaluable, setting it with `SET GLOBAL` does not survive a server restart AFAIK.

Answer (score 12):

On a **Windows** platform,

1. Find your **my.ini** configuration file.
2. In **my.ini** go to the `[mysqld]` section.
3. Add **`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=true`** without quotes and save the change.
4. Start **mysqld**

This worked for me (**windows 7 Ultimate 32bit**)

Comment: it probably couldnt work - the argument is missing -> see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp you have to add " = true/false"

Comment: edit `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` on debian buster.

Answer (score 6):

For me it worked to add the phrase **"explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = ON"** without quotes into the config file `my.ini`.

Make sure you add this phrase right underneath the [mysqld] statement in the config file.

You will find `my.ini` under `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7` if you had conducted the default installation of MySQL.

Answer (score 4):

On Windows you can run server with option key, no need to change ini files.

`"C:\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe" --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1`

Answer (score 4):

In your mysql command line: `SET explicit_defaults_for_timestamp=1`

Answer (score 1):

On my system (Windows 8.1), the problem was with the server configuration. The server worked for the first time when I installed it. However, I forgot to check the "run as a service" option and this caused all the problem. I tried all possible solutions available on SO but nothing worked. So, I decided to reinstall MySQL Workbench. On executing the same msi file that I earlier used to install MySQL workbench, I reconfigured the server and allowed to run the server as a service.

Comment: Right clicking the MySQL Notifier and launching the Installer, reconfigured my server as a service worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

On Windows -- open my.ini file, present at "C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6",  find "[mysqld]" (without quotes) in next line add explicit_defaults_for_timestamp and then save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm Using Windows 8.1 and I use this command

```
c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe
```

instead of

```
 c:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysqld
```

and it works fine..