# Forgot MySQL server v5.6 password, error timestamp

Tags: mysql

I forgot the password of my MySQL server ( v5.6 ) and it seems that I can't reset it.
I used this tutorial: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

I'm having problems with these commands:

```
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\
mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my-default.ini"
```

But I get the following error:

```
TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

I also tried it this way:

```
--defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my-default.ini" --init_file="path to the .txt file"
```

and I get the same error. Is there any way to reset the password?

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the error message? It seems to be asking you to add the `--explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` switch when starting, so for your second command I'd try this: `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my-default.ini" --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`.

Comment: I think this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701636/how-to-enable-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should follow [this guide here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) to reset your mySQL password. This must work (tried it, works) so double-check your path information and installation location.
EDIT: Just found [another method](http://blog.dotkam.com/2007/04/10/mysql-reset-lost-root-password/) in the comment section of the guide I mentioned above. Seems legit but I didn't try it.