# Timestamp error when attempting to run mysqld

Tags: windows, timestamp, mysql

When I attempt to run mysqld through the Command Prompt to enter that, I get an error saying:

```
[Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. 
Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for
more details).
```

I've tried pasting `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE` into the my.ini file, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Even I faced the same issue 
Try passing

> explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Go to mysql server installation directory 
C:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.6\
check for file my.ini 
if it is not there duplicate my-default.ini file any rename it to my.ini and add 
`explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1`
and save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more here.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

but I guess you only need to **run Command Prompt as Administrator**

also look at this question [How to enable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701636/how-to-enable-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following command and should work. Make sure add **--**

```
d:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld.exe --init-file=D:\\mysql-ini
t.txt --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```