# Error when starting MySQL server

Tags: mysql

I have a problem starting the MySql server. The log says:

```
2013-10-15 13:57:01 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details)
```

I now sombody solved this problem. Can help me??

Comment: How about reading the error message, i.e. either start the server with --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp flag, or change schema on the table with implicit DEFAULT on a TIMESTAMP? Besides that, this is a warning, this shouldn't block running the server, isn't there an error as well?

Comment: you need to check your logs at the time of starting mysql as mentioned warning is not the cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

Search for `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp` this might clear up some things.

[How to enable explicit_defaults_for_timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701636/how-to-enable-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp)