# Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully, When trying to install mysql using brew in Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: mysql, macos, installation

Trying to install mysql5.7 with brew on Mac OS High Sierra

I have used the following commands:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql/
brew install mysql@5.7
brew postinstall mysql@5.7
```

Got the below errors

```
2019-10-05T02:59:24.136970Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2019-10-05T02:59:24.138997Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2019-10-05T02:59:24.215676Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2019-10-05T02:59:24.232279Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2019-10-05T02:59:24.286214Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
2019-10-05T02:59:24.286281Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Because of which i couldn't able to do

```
mysql_secure_installation
```

which throws

```
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

If you are able to find your `my.cnf` file (for me, it was in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`) you should remove the below line:

```
mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: I had this problem as I had mysql v8 installed previously (also via homebrew).
Brew says as much: `A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built server starting up correctly.`

Comment: I had to also remove `/usr/local/var/mysql` before re-running `brew postinstall mysql@5.7`

Comment: Thank you this really helped! Yes even I had to remove all the data in `/usr/local/var/mysql`

Comment: For me, Homebrew 3.1.9 in Mac Big Sur 's my.cnf file location is /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

Comment: In Hombrew version 3.4.11 the my.cnf is located at '/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf' of mac OS Monterey

Answer (score 6):

Like @sbkrogers says, must to remove the line, but since I use Homebrew to install mysql@5.7:

1. My file is located on `/opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf`. Where remove
   `mysqlx-bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
2. After the first aborted installation, following folders need to be deleted:

   - `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7`
   - `/opt/homebrew/var/mysql`
3. ...then try to install again. `brew install mysql`
4. After the installation was success, restart terminal

Answer (score 1):

For our case, it is due to mysql was installed earlier before mariadb. Therefore the my.cnf is already created. The `my.cnf` from mysql is missing some lines needed for mariadb.

The steps we did to fix:

```bash
# uninstall mariadb 
brew remove mariadb

# rename my.cnf to something else
# the homebrew etc directory is on /opt/homebrew/etc
# cd /opt/homebrew/etc
mv my.cnf my.cnf.default

# re-install
brew install mariadb

# restart and check the status
brew services restart mariadb && brew service info mariadb
```