# brew install mariadb fails as system can not chown for auth_pam_tool

Tags: mariadb, homebrew

## brew

brew install not work. this is the log.

```
% brew install mariadb
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/mariadb-10.4.13.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/shingo/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/d56104142081a8230646ac3f245adf2414e515cd5f2aeeb0637614e9966e882c--mariadb-10.4.13.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Pouring mariadb-10.4.13.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql_install_db --verbose --user=shingo --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
Last 15 lines from /Users/shingo/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mariadb/post_install.01.mysql_install_db:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /usr/local/var/mysql that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://mariadb.org/jira

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall mariadb`
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

MySQL is configured to only allow connections from localhost by default

To start mariadb:
  brew services start mariadb
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  mysql.server start
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13: 744 files, 169.9MB
```

## I have tried to execute mysql_install_db

I have tried to execute `mysql_install_db` without brew. this is the log.
The brew displays only the last 15 lines, so I can't help it.

```
% /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql_install_db --verbose --user=shingo --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
chown: /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/lib/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool: Operation not permitted
Couldn't set an owner to '/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/lib/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool'.
It must be root, the PAM authentication plugin doesn't work otherwise..

Installing MariaDB/MySQL system tables in '/usr/local/var/mysql' ...
2020-05-29 22:13:03 0 [Note] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysqld (mysqld 10.4.13-MariaDB) starting as process 45440 ...
2020-05-29 22:13:03 0 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysqld: option '--innodb-large-prefix' requires an argument
2020-05-29 22:13:03 0 [ERROR] Parsing options for plugin 'InnoDB' failed.
2020-05-29 22:13:03 0 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
2020-05-29 22:13:03 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Installation of system tables failed!  Examine the logs in
/usr/local/var/mysql for more information.

The problem could be conflicting information in an external
my.cnf files. You can ignore these by doing:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql_install_db --defaults-file=~/.my.cnf

You can also try to start the mysqld daemon with:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --general-log &

and use the command line tool /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql
to connect to the mysql database and look at the grant tables:

    shell> /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysql -u root mysql
    mysql> show tables;

Try 'mysqld --help' if you have problems with paths.  Using
--general-log gives you a log in /usr/local/var/mysql that may be helpful.

The latest information about mysql_install_db is available at
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-system-tables-mysql_install_db
You can find the latest source at https://downloads.mariadb.org and
the maria-discuss email list at https://launchpad.net/~maria-discuss

Please check all of the above before submitting a bug report
at http://mariadb.org/jira
```

I noticed that the system can not `chown` for `auth_pam_tool` because Operation not permitted.

## auth_pam_tool permission

this is my permission the directory.

```
% ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/lib/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool
-r-xr-xr-x  1 shingo  staff  13608  5 10 04:28 /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/lib/plugin/auth_pam_tool_dir/auth_pam_tool
```

How to fix Operation not permitted?

Or is there any other reason why it cannot be installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self resolved.

## Anyway I gave it try start

Even though the installation was not successful, anyway I gave it try `% mysql.server start`.

### A error log file was created.

A error log file was created by starting mysql server.

the error log shows:

```
2020-05-30  8:47:10 0 [Warning] InnoDB: innodb_open_files 300 should not be greater than the open_files_limit 256
2020-05-30  8:47:10 0 [ERROR] /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.4.13/bin/mysqld: unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
2020-05-30  8:47:10 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

An unknown value in the `mysqlx-bind-address` seems to be causing the error.

## How to fix unknown variable

I found
[the same error question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58245118/warning-the-post-install-step-did-not-complete-successfully-when-trying-to-ins). This question discussed a `my.conf` file.

- `~/.my.conf` did not exist on my mac
- `/etc/my.conf` did not exist on my mac

this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-do-i-find-the-mysql-my-cnf-location) teach me the `my.conf` location.

Finally I found `my.conf` in `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`.Certainly the settings for `mysqlx-bind-address` were written in `my.conf`.

So `rm /usr/local/etc/my.cnf`, then brew reinstall SUCCESS!.

The `permission` was irrelevant at all.

Answer (score 1):

this work for me:

```
rm /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf
```