# How do I disable DEFAULT and ON UPDATE when creating a table

Tags: mysql, sql

After hours of debugging my PHP code, because the dates were being incorrectly stored, I realized that `XAMPP` was automatically adding a `DEFAULT` attribute and a `ON UPDATE` attribute to my `date_added` column.

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    date_added          timestamp
                        NOT NULL,

    last_updated        timestamp
                        NOT NULL
);
```

As you can see, I am clearly not setting a `DEFAULT` value or a `ON UPDATE` tag on my table creation code. However, if I go into phpmyadmin and look at the structure of this table, it looks like this: [image: Structure of table]

I tried to click on "change" and set `DEFAULT` to `None` and `ON UPDATE` to blank but it doesn't change it. Any suggestions on how I can remove these things?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the setting of the system variable `explicit_defaults_for_timestamp`, which in MySQL < 8.0.2, defaults to `OFF`. When it is `OFF`,

> If explicit_defaults_for_timestamp is disabled, the server enables
>   the nonstandard behaviors and handles TIMESTAMP columns as follows:
>
> - TIMESTAMP columns not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute are automatically declared with the NOT NULL attribute. Assigning such
>     a column a value of NULL is permitted and sets the column to the
>     current timestamp.
> - The first TIMESTAMP column in a table, if not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT or ON UPDATE attribute,
>     is automatically declared with the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON
>     UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP attributes.
> - TIMESTAMP columns following the first one, if not explicitly declared with the NULL attribute or an explicit DEFAULT attribute, are
>     automatically declared as DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' (the “zero”
>     timestamp). For inserted rows that specify no explicit value for such
>     a column, the column is assigned '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and no warning
>     occurs.
>
>   Depending on whether strict SQL mode or the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode is enabled, a default value of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' may be invalid.
>     Be aware that the TRADITIONAL SQL mode includes strict mode and
>     NO_ZERO_DATE. See Section 5.1.11, “Server SQL Modes”.

See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_explicit_defaults_for_timestamp).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701636/how-to-enable-explicit-defaults-for-timestamp) discusses how to change the setting.

Comment: is there a way to set this using php (when I make a mysqli connection)

Comment: You could try sending a query which sets the variable when you make the connection.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: `SET GLOBAL explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1`. If you can't do that, you would need to edit the MySQL configuration file as described in the question I linked.